# VS 2008 MULTI LAYERS C# project gives error on opening

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, msbuild

I have a **[MULTI LAYERS]** project built on VS2008, Last week the project was running and opening without any problem, But now when I try to open it, an error message appear:

[image]

If I click OK or close the message box, no projects in the solution will load like this:

[image]

And in the Registry, The path 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild' contains:

[image]

Please Help me and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many attempts I found the solution by download and install MSBuild Tools for VS 2015 from the following link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48159

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 1):

Tools Version 14 refers to the version used by Visual Studio 2015 - sounds as though the project file has been upgraded to a 2015 project.

Comment: OK, How to fix it!

Comment: Unfortunately the process is one-way so you'll need to restore the project files (and probably the whole solution) from a backup.